Mapping mws to sp-api... Amazon list price and sales rank
A beginner question. I've inherited an Amazon mws lookup site. I am having trouble digging through the new Amazon SP-SPI documentation in order to convert.
For starters I simply need the Amazon list price and sales ranking for an ASIN (which is a book). Can anyone tell me what API call to use and the exact field names that these would be returned in. I've been searching through the Catalog and Product Pricing calls.
I am able to make calls using the API but with the mountain of documention still cannot determine where the actual Amazon list price and sales ranking would be returned.

What you need to do is call the Catalog Items API and, in particular, the getCatalogItem call. Ensure to set salesRanks for the includedData parameter. You will find what you are looking for in the response inside the salesRanks element, and inside the classificationRanks and displayGroupRanks contained parameters.
In order to get the price informations, you need to call the Product Pricing v0 API and, in particular, the getItemOffers.
In order to perform this call you must set a value for the ItemCondition parameter. You can optionally set a value for the CustomerType parameter, which will let you get price informations for B2C or B2B customers.
You can then check the Summary element, which contains:

LowestPrices
BuyBoxPrices
ListPrice

